# Compact horizontal guage Matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

How to create a compact horizontal gauge like for example a thermometer for temperature, barometer for  pressure using Matplotlib. The scale of the gauge will be split into ranges; each range denoting high-high, high. low and low-low and a pointer reading the value? Is it possible to create such a gauge in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a colorbar.

For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 2))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.4, 0.8, 0.2])

bounds = [-20, -10, 0, 10, 20]
labels = ('low-low', 'low', 'high', 'high-high')

cmap = mpl.cm.coolwarm
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=bounds[0], vmax=bounds[-1])

cb = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(
    ax,
    cmap=cmap,
    norm=norm,
    orientation='horizontal',
    boundaries=bounds,
    label='temperature (degrees celcius)',
)

for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    xpos = float((2*i + 1))/(2*len(labels))
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(xpos, 0.5), xycoords='axes fraction', ha='center', va='center')

plt.show()
```

Which produces something like this:

[image: temperature guage example]

For more info see [these examples in the matplotlib docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/colorbar_only.html).

Comment: Fantastic. thanks. How to mark the value as a scale pointer? Say, if my temperature is 5 DegC.